# prove that $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1-\cos x}{x} \,dx < \frac{\pi^2}{64}$

Tags: integral-inequality

prove that $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1-\cos x}{x} \,dx <  \frac{\pi^2}{64}$

I showed that in 
$$ \forall x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{4}] \quad  \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1-\cos x}{x} \,dx \le \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})}{\frac{\pi}{4}} \,dx = 1 -\frac{\sqrt2}{2} $$
but it's not good enough

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the fact that $\sin(x)\le x$ for $x\ge0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{1-\cos(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{2\sin^2(x/2)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}\cdot\sin(x/2)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\int_0^{\pi/4}1\cdot\frac x2\,\mathrm{d}x\\[4pt]
&=\frac{\pi^2}{64}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Mate, you probably have the best styling on the whole site, damn. I just know that this is robjohn from your style :P

Comment: @HasanSaad: Thanks! and thanks for fixing the typo in the last line.

Comment: You're welcome mate. :)

Answer (score 4):

Another way forward is to recall the Taylor series for the cosine

$$\cos x =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!} \tag 1$$

Noting that for $0\le x\le \pi/4$ the terms of the series in $(1)$ alternate signs and are decreasing monotonically. Therefore, we have

$$\cos x \ge 1-\frac12 x^2$$

so that

$$\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\le \frac12 x$$

Finally, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\,dx &\le \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac12 x\, dx\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{64}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: You might want to show that $1-\cos(x)-\frac{x^2}2$ is concave and its derivative and value at $x=0$ is $0$. This shows that $1-\cos(x)\le\frac{x^2}2$. This is a bit cleaner than worrying about the trailing part of the series.

Comment: @robjon Well, yes, but the trailing part alternates sign so the inequality holds for $x$ in the interval of interest.

Comment: And the terms are monotonically decreasing. Just one more thing you need to state and check when truncating series.

Comment: @robjon All evident for the excrutiatingly well-known series for the cosine, don't you agree.

Comment: However, here we are using $$\cos(x) = 1-\frac12x^2+\frac1{24}x^4 +O\!\left(x^6\right)$$ to derive $$\frac{1-\cos(x)}x\le\frac12x$$ and without some backstage help, the floor show is a bit confusing. It is okay as a way to point the OP, however.

Comment: @robjohn I had been working from a "smart phone" and am back on the laptop.  I can better understand your perspective now and agree that for some users, the development could be obfuscating.  So, stepping back, I have rewritten a bit and hope that this proves more useful for a broader range of possible "readers."  And I know that you need help here too since you're a novice at math ... LOL.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $1-\cos(x)=2\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ and $0 \leq \frac{\sin(t)}{t} < 1$ for all $t \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.  If done properly, you should get $\int\limits_0^{\pi/4}\,\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}\,\text{d}x<\frac{\pi^2}{64}$ (which I think you meant to do, since $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$ is a very weak bound).

Comment: yes I meant 64, edited

Answer (score 1):

Since:
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) $$
over the interval $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right]$ we have:
$$ \frac{1-\cos x}{x}=\left(\frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}\right)^2\cdot\frac{x}{2}\leq\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2}\right)^2\frac{x}{2} $$
so:
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\,dx \color{red}{\leq} \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2}\right)^2\frac{x}{2}\,dx = \frac{\pi^2}{64}-\frac{191\,\pi^2}{3\cdot 2^{18}}.$$